# How to add a question about a problem?

Tags: discussion

I am having trouble figuring out how to ask a question about someone's question in the SharePoint forum. For example, I don't have an answer but want to suggest "Please post the section of your log files with that correlation ID" as a follow-up.

I have posted this sort of thing to the Answer section in the past, and a helpful person "moved" it to be indented under the main question. I have looked at "edit the question" and that doesn't seem to be the right place either.  I think I am missing something simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment on a question (and on answers) if you have enough reputation.

[You need 50 rep to be able to comment.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment)

Comment: Yup. To clarify, this is the ability to *comment everywhere*. You can comment on your own questions/answers without 50 rep.

Comment: I would also add.. try answering a few questions to get that required rep! :)